# What is covered as part of a definition?

Tags: epistemology, terminology

A cat is defined as an animal with this scientific classification 
Kingdom:    Animalia
Phylum: Chordata
Class:  Mammalia
Order:  Carnivora
Suborder:   Feliformia
Family: Felidae
Genus:  Felis
But, if my cat is outside at time t, is my cat defined to be outside at time t?
What if I say, I am going to define a cat: This cat is defined to be outside at time t? is that possible? What part of philosophy is this (if it is)? If anyone could point me in the direction of where I can learn more about this it would be greatly appreciated. Danke sehr schon mal

Comment: We define *words* (i.e. concepts) and not individuals (i.e. objects). See [Definitions](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/definitions/).

Comment: You might be interested in the distinction between essential and accidental properties that goes back to the ancient Greeks.

Comment: The notion of definition is indeed linguistic but perhaps what you're after is a distinction between properties your cat *must* have (as part of its nature) and the properties it happens to have but could lack. Then your intuition would be that a proper definition of "cathood" must refer to those essential properties. This is in line with the idea that a definition holds as a matter of (a priori) necessity, while the fact for your cat to be at a certain place is contingent, not necessary.

Comment: If position was part of your cat's definition, your cat would cease to be your cat after moving which seems absurd. Beyond the linguistic/ontological distinction, and the accidental/essential distinction, the type/token distinction seems also relevant here: are you trying to define a proper name that refers to an object ("Felix the cat") or a kind term ("cat"in general) that refers to a natural kind? I guess you could reformulate the question by making these three distinctions and make clear what you're asking exactly.

Answer (score 1):

[Words are universals](https://books.google.com/books?id=vs4LCmY_N-8C&lpg=PA153&vq=all%20words%20classify&pg=PA24#v=snippet&q=%22a%20word%20is%20a%20universal%22&f=false), i.e. all words classify. "Cat" denotes a class of similar animals. Suppose there is a cat whose name is Garfield; it is possible that you saw or imagined this particular cat. But no one ever saw *cat* or *a cat*; no one can even imagine *cat* or *a cat* because our sense experiences are particulars.

Dictionary definitions depend on a minimum vocabulary, the definitions of which must be [ostensive](https://books.google.com/books?id=vs4LCmY_N-8C&q=ostensive#v=snippet&q=ostensive&f=false) in order to assign meanings to these words.

Most people were taught the word "cat" by someone who pointed at different animals while uttering "this is a cat." After several illustrations, most people can recognize the similarity and identify other similar animals as cat.

Most children, who learned alphabet from the blackboard, have no problem with recognizing much smaller prints on paper. Few people say I do not recognize this "A" because the "A" I learned is a lot bigger than  this one. The human brains have the ability to classify.

Suppose you are speaking with someone whose definition of "cat" is the same as yours and you want to define your cat. In order to do this, all it takes is to point out a quality that is possessed by your cat and not by other cats.

For further discussion, see ["An Inquiry of Meaning and Truth"](https://books.google.com/books?id=vs4LCmY_N-8C&lpg=PA153&vq=all%20words%20classify&pg=PA24#v=onepage&q=%22What%20is%20A%20word%22&f=false) by Bertrand Russell.